# wxFilePickerCtrl not actualizing widget after setting path

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I've got a problem with wxFilePickerCtrl. I tried to set a path with method SetPath(), and it did not work, the path is setted, because i can get it from GetPath(), but the widget still displays path (None).

Here is my code(simplified to two classes). Do you have any idea how can I does it properly? I tried diffrent wxFilePickerCtrl methods from documentation, but results were the same.

main.hpp:

```
#ifndef MAIN_HPP
#define MAIN_HPP

#include <wx/wx.h>

#include "panel.hpp"

    class MyApp : public wxApp
    {
        public:
            bool OnInit();

        private:
            Panel* _panel;
    };

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.hpp"

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    _panel = new Panel();
    _panel->Show(true);
    return true;
}
```

panel.hpp:

```
#ifndef PANEL_HPP
#define PANEL_HPP

#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/filepicker.h>    

class Panel : public wxFrame
{
    public:
        Panel();

    private:
        wxFilePickerCtrl* _filePicker;
        wxBoxSizer* _sizer;
};      

#endif
```

panel.cpp:

```
#include "panel.hpp"

Panel::Panel() : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "MyApp", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(850, 450))
{
    _sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    _filePicker = new wxFilePickerCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, "filePicker");
    sizer->Add(_filePicker, 2, wxALIGN_CENTER, 2);
    //file does not matter so in examplie I tried to set to main.cpp
    _filePicker->SetPath("/some_path/main.cpp"); 
    this->SetSizer(_sizer);
    this->Centre();
}
```

Comment: how did you configured wxWidgets? Can you reproduce the behavior in the `widgets` or `dialogs` sample?

Comment: I'm developing a medium sized app for half a year now and everything except for this function works well, for installation I used this guide from wxWidgets site: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Install#Linux

Comment: can you reproduce it in the sample? Also, can you post you EXACT configure line?

Comment: Do you mean my make file or my commands from installation process, cause I'm not sure.

Comment: whe you build wxWidgets you did `../configure <set_of_options> && make`. I'm looking for that <set_of_options> part. And also any and all C{XX}/LDFLAGS you passed to configure, if any.

Comment: I used only this 2 flags: --with-gtk=3 --with-opengl

Comment: can you build and run the `widgets` or the `dialogs` sample? and try to reproduce it there?

Comment: All you do is: `cd wxWidgets-3.1.4/buildGTK/samples/dialogs && make && ./dialogs` or `cd wxWidgets-3.1.4/buildGTK/samples/widgets && make && ./widgets`

Comment: I tried seting file name in dialog sample and the outcom was the same as in my example.

Comment: Ok It will work when i set dialog style to text ctrl, I tested it on widgets app, where is the example of file picker, but it never updates, when path display is static.

Comment: what is you GTK version? Maybe you found a bug in the library... Try to post on wx-users ML to see if you get a reply from core wx-devs. Give all the info above - wx version, port (wxGTK/Linux(Ubuntu)), GTK version, and steps to reproduce in a sample.

Answer (score 1):

This is [a GTK limitation](https://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/19163) which only shows the name of existing files in this control (so this should work if your `/some_path/main.cpp` actually exists). I don't see any way to make `GtkFileChooserButton` show the file name if it doesn't exist, so I don't think this can be fixed, unfortunately.

Generally speaking, this control is really supposed to be used for loading existing files in GTK.

Comment: I'm seeing precisely the same behaviour, and the path I'm giving it _does_ exist....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set it to a file, then you have to use `SetFilename`

```
wxFileName fn = "C:/src/wxWidgets.dev/samples/widgets/native.cpp";
filePicker->SetFileName(fn);
```

Comment: I don't know whether it is a Linux issue(I'm coding under Ubuntu), but it did not work in my case either. Still my widget displays (None).

Comment: I tested here against a github build (should be 3.x)  on windows and it works for me. I don't see what `SetPath` is really for, because in the sample code they are using `SetInitialDirectory("path")` instead, but without a filename of course.

Comment: I am using wxWidgets 3.1.4 so it is not the problem here.